# how to match nocase c-string in boost multi_index_container by hash

Tags: c++, boost, multi-index

check out code below, i overload hash function and string-equal function for nocase-c-string key(const char*), but the result is not what i expected: the main function will print not found, how to make it matched?

```
struct hash_c_string
{
    std::size_t operator()(const char *ctx) const
    {
        return MurmurHash2(ctx, strlen(ctx),static_cast<size_t>(0xc70f6907UL));
    }
};
typedef struct  {
    const char * name;
}PortMapConfig;
struct by_name{};
struct CompareEqual
{   
    inline bool operator()(const char* left, const char* right) const
    {
        return strcasecmp(left, right)==0;
    }
};
using namespace boost::multi_index;
 
typedef
boost::multi_index_container<
        PortMapConfig,
        indexed_by<
      hashed_unique<tag<by_name>, member<PortMapConfig, const char *, &PortMapConfig::name>, hash_c_string, CompareEqual>

        >
> StuContainer;
int main() {
    StuContainer con;
    PortMapConfig st1 = {"Uplink0"};
    con.insert(st1);
    auto &indexofName = con.get<by_name>();
    const char * s = "uplink0";
    auto itr = indexofName.find(s);
    if(itr != indexofName.end()){
        std::cout << "name:"<<itr->name << std::endl;
    }
    else
        std::cout << "not found!!!"<< std::endl;
 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your hash function and your equivalence function don't match. The equivalence function ignores case, the hash does not, so two equivalent things have different hashes. The behaviour is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're attempting to hash by a derived property, namely a case-folded name.

This is going to be expensive even if done right¹. All the signals here indicate that you might be doing these in the name of performance. If you need the case-insensitive lookup, I suggest to reify a key to index on, so you can have natural hash and equality on them.

> ¹ Importantly, as the commenter already points out, your solution has [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because the hash/equality functions don't agree

You might even pre-fold the lookup key to avoid repeat efforts.

In this example I'd strongly suggest using string views, considering not hashing at all (have you profiled it with your load factors?).

Making your sample work, and also cleaned up a little:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fe271500496c6c77)**

```
#include <boost/locale.hpp>
#include <boost/locale/conversion.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace bmi = boost::multi_index;

static auto inline fold_case(std::string_view sv) {
    return boost::locale::fold_case(sv.data());
}

struct PortMapConfig {
    /*explicit*/ PortMapConfig(std::string_view name): name(name) {}

    std::string_view name;
    std::string name_key = fold_case(name);

    struct Hash {
        std::size_t operator()(std::string_view sv) const {
            return boost::hash_value(sv); // TODO(sehe): murmur instead
        }
    };

    using Equal = std::equal_to<std::string_view>;
};

using StuContainer = bmi::multi_index_container<
    PortMapConfig,
    bmi::indexed_by<bmi::hashed_unique<
        bmi::tag<struct by_name>,
        bmi::member<PortMapConfig, std::string, &PortMapConfig::name_key>,
        PortMapConfig::Hash,
        PortMapConfig::Equal>
    >>;

int main() {
    std::locale::global(boost::locale::generator()("en_US.UTF-8"));
    StuContainer con { {"Uplink0"}, {"Uplink1"} };

    if (auto itr = con.find(fold_case("uplink1")); itr != con.end()) {
        std::cout << "name:" << itr->name << " (" << itr->name_key << ")\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
name:Uplink1 (uplink1)
```